# sum last counter values in aggregateWindow

Tags: flux-influxdb

I have a measurement series with tags and values as counters.
I would like to display the sum of all values per aggregateWindow as a daily overview.

Here are some measurements and the result I like to have
[measurements and results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMx99.png)

This is the current status.
I would like to sum up the individual values as shown in the picture
[InfluxDB GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmQL4.png)

Any help very welcome, thanks